# How to order a IEnumerable<T> of anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, anonymous-types

See the code below, I don't know why my ordering is not working, any ideas?

```
var orderSample = new { ProductName = "", Qty = 0, UserFullName = "" };
var ordersList = (new[] { orderSample }).ToList();

//loop thru another collection and fill ordersList by adding an order at a time
ordersList.Add(new { ProductName = "Product1", Qty = 5, UserFullName = "Mr. Smith" });

//sort the orders by name - DOESN'T WORK
ordersList.OrderBy(p => p.ProductName);

gvReport3.DataSource = ordersList;
gvReport3.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var sortedList = ordersList.OrderBy(p => p.ProductName).ToList();
```

[OrderBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) returns a sorted collection, it does not modify the ordersList.

If you need to modify the ordersList, use Sort instead.